# Clear terminal / console in Crystal (CLI)

Tags: crystal-lang

How does one clear the console like with `console.clear()` in Node, but on Crystal.

I have searched around for a while but there seems to be no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no fully standardized and ubiquitous way to clear a terminal. Most terminals recognize a special character sequence, though.

The string that has worked very reliably (and has been in my Bash aliases) is [`\33c\e[3J`](https://www.google.com/search?q=printf+%27%5C33c%5Ce[3J%27):

```
print "\33c\e[3J"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("\033[2J")
```

Does the job, but positions the content towards the bottom.